# Ejecutar archivo *.sql con python SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma que usando Python se ejecuten archivos .sql almacenados en una ruta específica, he intentando estas opciones pero fallan:

```
cursor.execute(file(PATH_TO_FILE).read())
```

pero esto no funciona porque cursor.execute solo puede ejecutar un comando sql a la vez. Mi script sql contiene varias declaraciones sql. También estaba intentando

```
cursor.execute('source %s'%PATH_TO_FILE)
```

Pero también falló, me recomendaron trabajarlo de esta forma pero tampoco pude:

```
for line in open(PATH_TO_FILE):
    cursor.execute(line)
```

Creo que esto supone que tiene una instrucción SQL por línea en su archivo.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de el archivo SQL a ejecutar? ¿Cual es el tamaño de estos?

Comment: En este link esta un ejemplo
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eadBPvjlLJ3v6fBTAwQlGhEnHpDgWhs3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre que el archivo `.sql` se corresponda a un conjunto de clausulas `SQL` válidas, lo que deberías hacer es leer el contenido completamente en una variable, y ejecutar `cursor.execute()` pasandole dicha variable

```
with open(PATH_TO_FILE, 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read()
  cursor.execute(data)
```

Entiendo, aunque desconozco (creo que son 2Gb), existe un límite en el tamaño de la consulta que vas a enviar mediante `cursor.execute(data)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ayudo con el problema

Answer (score 1):

Si se quiere algo más robusto con control de error, con visualización de barra de progreso usando el componente, https://pypi.org/project/alive-progress/

Para separar las lineas de los comandos SQL usar `sqlparse`

```py
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import time
from pathlib import Path
import sqlparse

#============================ EDIT MYSQL CONFIGURATION ============================
mysql_config = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': '',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'devstore',
        'port': '3306',
        'ssl_disabled': True
    }
#================================== END OF EDIT ===================================

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

def execute_sqlfile(cnx, fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as fd:
        sqlCommands = sqlparse.split(fd.read())
        title = Path(fileName).stem
        total = len(sqlCommands)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        with alive_bar(total, dual_line=True, title=title.ljust(15)) as bar:
            for sqlCommand in sqlCommands:
                try:
                    cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
                    cnx.commit()
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                except (Exception) as e :
                    print(bcolors.WARNING + "Warning: Command skipped" + bcolors.ENDC, e)
                bar()
        cursor.close
#================================== MAIN SCRIPT ===================================

print(bcolors.HEADER + "DevStore Maker v1.0.0"+ bcolors.ENDC)

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
    if cnx.is_connected():
        print(bcolors.OKGREEN + 'connected to database' + bcolors.ENDC)

    print(bcolors.OKCYAN + 'create tables and erase data' + bcolors.ENDC)
    execute_sqlfile(cnx, 'sql_scripts/dev_store_db.sql')

    cnx.close()
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN + " Finished All " + bcolors.ENDC)

except Error as e:
    print(bcolors.FAIL + "mysql DB connection error" + bcolors.ENDC)
    print(e)
```